# How to code this calculation in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Im trying to code a calculation in Access that involves the SUM of some values plus the result of an IF statement.

Here is a table of the kind of data I'm dealing with (from 'CostBaseQuery)

```
CompanyName Year    AssetName  DatapointID  Datapointname                DatapointValue
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4025         Active operated wells           129
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4058         API gravity of oil              38.5563255
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4032         Number of gas lift wells        70
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4033         Number of wells with ESPs       0
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4036         Wells with CO2 production       25
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4035         Wells with H2S production       9
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4038         Wells with high pressure        0
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4037         Wells with high temperature     0
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4034         Wells with scale production     42
CompanyA    2011    AssetA     4039         Wells with wax                  0
```

The calculation needs to **SUM(DatapointValue)** WHERE DatapointID IN (4032,4033,4035,4036,4037,4038,4039)

**PLUS the value returned from the IF Statement**

IF (API gravity of oil <=5 or >20, Use the value of ActiveOperatedWells, Else 0)

I tried to use the following method to code the calculation but it outputs data on each iteration of the SUM rather than carrying out the SUM calculation and THEN the IF statement.

```
SELECT qb1.CompanyName, qb1.AssetName, qb1.Year, 
(SUM(qb1.DatapointValue) 
+ IIF(qb2.DatapointValue>=5, 
       IIF(qb2.DatapointValue<20, qb3.DatapointValue, 0), 0)) 
AS NumberOfWellCompletions

FROM (CostBaseQuery AS qb1 
     INNER JOIN CostBaseQuery AS qb2 
          ON qb1.CompanyYearAssetID=qb2.CompanyYearAssetID) 
     INNER JOIN CostBaseQuery AS qb3 
          ON qb1.CompanyYearAssetID=qb3.CompanyYearAssetID

WHERE qb1.DatapointID IN (4032,4033,3036,4035,4038,4037,4034,4039)
AND qb2.DatapointID=4058 AND qb3.DatapointID=4025

GROUP BY qb1.CompanyName, qb1.AssetName, qb1.Year, 
qb1.DatapointValue, qb2.DatapointValue, qb3.DatapointValue
```

Any help would be much appreciated and I hope this makes more sense than my previous rambling!

Comment: What's wrong with your attempt?

Comment: I get an message that there is a SYNTAX error in the FROM clause and Access highlights 'FROM CostBaseQuery AS qb2'

Answer (score 1):

The question isn't really useful to other SO users and you don't state your actual problem but if I indent your query the way I like, like this,

```
SELECT
              b.CompanyName
            , b.AssetName
            , b.Year
            , (
                b.CalculationResult + 
                mp.CalculationResult
              ) AS NumberOfWellCompletions

    FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                          CompanyName
                        , AssetName
                        , Year
                        , SUM(q1.DatapointValue) AS CalculationResult 
                FROM
                        CostBaseQuery AS q1 
                WHERE
                        DatapointID in (
                            4032,
                            4033,
                            3036,
                            4035,
                            4038,
                            4037,
                            4034,
                            4039) 
                GROUP BY
                          CompanyName
                        , AssetName
                        , Year
        ) AS b 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT
                          CompanyName
                        , AssetName
                        , Year
                        , (
                            SUM(
                                IIF(
                                    qb2.DatapointValue>=5, 
                                    IIF(
                                        qb2.DatapointValue<20, 
                                        qb3.DatapointValue,
                                        0),
                                    0)
                          ) 
                FROM
                        CostBaseQuery qb3                   
                WHERE
                        qb3.CompanyName = qb2.CompanyName
                    AND 
                        qb3.AssetName = qb2.AssetName
                    AND
                        qb3.Year = qb2.Year 
                    AND
                        qb3.DatapointID = 4025                   
                GROUP BY 
                          CompanyName
                        , AssetName
                        , Year
        )
    // What is going on here, this doesn't make sense.
    ) AS CalculationResult 
FROM 
          CostBaseQuery AS qb2 
WHERE 
          DatapointID = 4058 
GROUP BY
            CompanyName
          , AssetName
          , Year
 ) AS mp 
    ON 
            (b.CompanyName = mp.CompanyName)
        AND 
            (b.AssetName = mp.AssetName)
        AND
            (b.Year = mp.Year);
```

I can see that you have the wrong number of brackets, so like the Access Parser says you have a syntax error.

If I were inclined to write your query for you, I would need more info about your database shcema. However, you should have a go at writing some SQL that can be parsed.